# Show an error when Evaluate Match doesn't find it's criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code working without any issues, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work with an `On Error`

```
row_num2 = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('" & ws1.Name & "'!A:A=""" & variable1 & """)*('" & ws1.Name & "'!B:B=""" & variable2 & """)*('" & ws1.Name & "'!G:G=""" & variable3 & """),0)")
```

I've tired wrapping it with

```
On Error GoTo ErrMsg
```

```
ErrMsg:
    MsgBox "error"
Exit Sub
```

This works fine if there is an error, but if it is correct then it still shows the "error" MsgBox and Exit's the Sub

Comment: Consider using `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Application.Evaluate method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) does not throw an exception that you can catch with `On Error …` instead it returns an error value that can be tested with the [IsError function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iserror-function).

```
If IsError(row_num2) Then
    MsgBox "error in evaluate"
End If
```

As Mathieu suggested in his comment you can alternatively use 
`Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`
which throws an exception that can be caught with `On Error …` or `Application.Match` that returns an error value for `IsError`.

See [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match).

Comment: That's it, that seems to have sorted it out. Thanks for that!